# does android OS creates new instance of Activity or brings up an old activity which has been pushed into the Activity stack

Tags: android

i m finding solution. my queston is

for each startActivity(intent), does android OS creates new  instance of Activity or brings up an old activity which has been pushed into the Activity stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the Flags that you set on the Intent, see:  [public Intent setFlags (int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29)

Comment: hello sir i m new in android ,so  i dont unable to get.

Comment: hello sir i m new in android ,so  i dont unable to get.

Comment: Well, if you click on that link and inspect all the links that start FLAG_ACTIVITY... (there are quite a few) they will tell you how starting the activity with that flag set affects the activity stack. You would start the activity like                           Intent i = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to bring up the old activity,
why don't you use PendingIntent.getActivity() 
it will get it and create it if it doesn't exist (unless you set the flag FLAG_NO_CREATE)
you can check about it here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html